# In FileA, why do evaluated strings extracted from $fileB = file_get_content(FileB.php) and handling variables defined in FileA result in unset values?

Tags: php, eval

I am a new questioner but a long time reader and I can't seem to find a solution to my PHP code.

I am trying to send and email after a form contact has been submitted. Piece of cake until I decided I wanted my html email saved in a different file rather than having it defined as a string within my form process php file. I have to say I find it much more easier to edit the layout of the message this way. 
It turns out it is no easy task, though.

I have "contact-form-process.php"

- parsing the information submitted through the form;
- adding that information to an array,

i.e.

```
$formdata = array( 
  'first-name' => $_POST['first-name'], 
  'last-name' => $_POST['last-name'], 
  'email' => $_POST['email'], 
  'message-subject' => filter_var($_POST['message-subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), 
  'message-body' => filter_var($_POST['message-body'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), 
);
```

and "sender-copy.php" which

- is the actual html email that I am sending out;
- performs some simple operations with variables defined in "contact-form-process.php",

i.e.

```
<p>
  Dear <?php $value = (isset($formdata['first-name']) ? $formdata['first-name'] : 'NOT-SET'), 
</p>
```

Now back to "contact-form-process.php", in it I include the html email body as a string (`$message = file_get_contents('sender-copy.php', TRUE);`) and treat it to evaluate PHP code snippets it contains:

```
$message = preg_replace_callback    (
                            '/<\?php(.+)\?>/', 
                            function ($match) {
                                eval($match[1]); 
                                return $value; 
                            }, 
                            $message
                        );
```

So now I have difficulty in retrieving $formdata array values from the evaluated PHP snippets in the "sender-copy.php" string. 
Here is a copy of my output:

```
<p>
  Dear NOT-SET, 
</p>
```

Anyone? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript, PHP does not inherit variables from the parent scope. This means that inside your `preg_replace_callback` callback, `$formdata` *does not exist*.

Fortunately, there is an easy way to inherit it:

```
function($match) use ($formdata) { ... }
```

That said, I would strongly recommend changing your approach. You could do something like this:

```
ob_start();
require("sender-copy.php");
$message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Alternatively, and much more safely, you can change your "sender-copy" to this:

```
<p>Dear {first-name},</p>
```

And use this replacement method:

```
$message = preg_replace_callback("/\{([^}]+)\}/",function($m) use ($formdata) {
    if( isset($formdata[$m[1]])) return $formdata[$m[1]];
    return "NOT-SET";
},$message);
```

Comment: Great! Problem solved, thank you very much. 
I am now looking for a way not to crash my <style> content in the html email body, since your suggestion, though a good one, seems to pass all my of css rules as keys for the $formdata array. 
This is the reason why I chose to use the <?php ?> tags at first.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Well, you could use `{{...}}` as your boundary (and update the regex accordingly). You can use any boundary, really, provided it doesn't risk cropping up in your text.